# Drupal login redirects to the login page again

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, shared-hosting

I'm having problems after moving a Drupal website to a new server. Initially, no assets were being loaded correctly as Drupal was trying to load them from an URL such as this:

> http://www.my-drupal-website.com/css/...

The server administrator apparently specified the host name of the website to be *"www.my-drupal-website.com"* in the Apache configuration file, however, he has not yet switched the DNSs of the domain to point to this host, due to some other issues. So actually, this website is now located at the following URL:

> https://somehost.com/somefolder/my-drupal-website.com/httpdocs/

In order to make it work, I changed the **$base_url** variable in **settings.php**, and now assets are loading correctly. However, a new problem became apparent, and that is the fact that login is not working. I enter my credentials, and I am redirected again at the homepage of the website, with the log-in form being displayed again. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the ReWriteBase in your .htaccess file.  Anything after the root domain should be added in the the ReWriteBase.